# Promises como retorno de função em node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize-js

Estou utilizando o framework Sequelize.js. para realizar consultas no banco, o resultado da função `find` retorna um objeto com 3 métodos: `success`, `error` e `complete`

**Ex.:**

```
models.ItensPedido.findAll( {where : {PedidoId: req.params.pedidoId}})
    .success( function( pedidos ) {
    res.send(200, pedidos);
    next;
})
.error( function(err) {
    console.log("Erro ao listar itens do pedido", req.params, err);
    res.send(500, "Erro ao listar itens do pedido: ", err);
    next();
})
```

Tentei fazer uma função que retornasse do mesmo jeito, mas sem sucesso

```
function validateLogin( pemail, ppwd ) {
    return function () {
        var successfull = false;
        var error;
        var user;

        exports.success = function ( userSuccess ) { 
            if (!successful) retrun; 

            userSuccess(user);
        }
        exports.error = function ( userError ) {
            if (!error) {retrun;} 
            userError(error);
        }

    models.User.find( { where: Sequelize.and({email: pemail}, {pwd: ppwd}) })
        .success( function (foundUser) {
           if (!user) {error = "User not found."; return;}
           user = foundUser;
           successfull = true;
        })
        error( function (err) {
           error = err;
        })

    }
}
```

mas sempre tenho como retorno que o objeto não possui um método `success`

a ideia é poder utilizar da seguinte forma:

```
validateLogin( "a@b.com", "123456")
    .success( { //logica de sucesso  } )
    .error( { //logica de erro } );
```

hoje consigo o resultado esperado da seguinte forma, passando os callbacks para o método:

```
validateLogin( "a@b.com", "123456", doOnSuccessLogin, doOnErrorLogin);
```

mas para isso preciso que os dois callbacks seja declarados dentro da mesma função pelo closure dos parametros do `restify` para responder a chamada rest

Como retornar um objeto, de forma assíncrona, com métodos após a execução da consulta, em nodejs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem umas partes do seu código que não entendi bem, mas respondendo à pergunta, retorne um *objeto* e não uma função:

```
function validateLogin( pemail, ppwd ) {
    return {
       success: function() {},
       error: function() {}
    };
}
```

---

Considerando o seu update, sugiro retornar a própria "promessa" (ou seja lá o que o o Sequelize implementou aí) retornada pelo `models.User.find`. Assim:

```
function validateLogin( pemail, ppwd ) {
    return models.User.find( { where: Sequelize.and({email: pemail}, {pwd: ppwd}) });
}

// USO:

validateLogin( "a@b.com", "123456")
    .success( function(foundUser) {  } )
    .error( function(err) { } );
```

Comment: Alterei o título. Depois do seu último post vi que o sequelize realmente utiliza promises.

Comment: Teve algo que faltou explicar? Não entendi bem a recompensa!

Comment: Tentei encontrar uma explicação de como utilizar as promisses por mim mesmo, daí quis mais visibilidade na pergunta. Mas depois encontrei um curso online no site http://nodeschool.io/. Mas ainda assim sua resposta me ajudou a solucionar o problema. Obrigado!